# Is there a way to plot a "function string" in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Example: The user types "(x^2 + 5)^3" into the terminal and the script plots the function like WolframAlpha would do.

Is there an easy way to do that in python?

The function might include abs(), sqrt() etc.

Thanks in advance for your responses

Comment: Maybe take a look at sympy to see if it has a way to parse expressions like this.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Another option would be to do something involving `eval`, (i.e. eval their function in a loop with different values of `x`) but then you have to trust the user not to enter malicious Python code, or you need to sanitize it very carefully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using eval with an inputted X or default x:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import re


def get_variables(input_string):
    count = 0
    matches = re.findall(r'(?i)[a-z]', input_string)
    return set(matches) #returns unique variables

function = input('Input Function: ')
variables = get_variables(function)
print(variables, type(variables), function)
varDict = {v: np.arange(100) for v in variables} #maps the variable names to some default range
for v in variables: #changes the function string to work with the newly defined variables
    pattern = r'\b%s\b' %v
    function = re.sub(pattern,r'varDict["%s"]' %v,function)
answer = eval(function) #evaluates the function


if len(variables) == 1:
    plt.plot(*varDict.values(),answer) #plot the results, in this case two dimensional
else:
    ax = plt.axes(projection="3d")
    ax.plot3D(*varDict.values(),answer) # line
    #ax.scatter3D(*varDict.values(),answer); #scatter
    
plt.show()
```

You can change the 3d settings if you want a scatterplot or add logic to make a shape (ie using meshgrid)

Just be sure that the eval statements are fully sanitized. This also requires the function to be inputted in python syntax (** not ^), unless you want to add functions to edit common syntax differences in the string.

Comment: If you don't want to use eval, you can map the operators in the strings to functions that take the arguments from the correct positions such as: function_dict['+'] = my_add. Then you could parse the string to determine  the arguments for my_add in the string 'a+b' are a and b. You wouldn't have to worry about sanitization but it would be a lot more tedious.

Comment: Thanks! I won't just copy your answer, but it helped really well solving this problem.